# Can the same O2 sensor provide narrowband and wideband output simultaneously?

Tags: o2-sensor, wideband

Is there an O2 sensor that has wideband and narrowband readings all-in-one?

I wanted something like this to get a good air fuel ratio readout while keeping the stock ECU which uses narrowband.

Comment: All O2 sensors are narrowband sensors. On wideband sensors, an oxygen pump is incorporated, and the needed O2 current to keep the sensor stoich is used to guess the AFR more precisely. If you don't make use of the oxygen pump, a wideband sensor won't differ from a narrowband one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the sensor itself, but there are controllers that can perform the conversion.

They are capable of simulating the narrowband signal using the wideband O2 reading and send it to the ECU, while maintaining a separate channel to preserve the actual wideband reading.

The enthusiast community shows a lot of love for the [Innovate LC](http://www.innovatemotorsports.com/products/lc2.php) series (no affiliation), and a quick web search reveals many guides on how to perform this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one, that does not mean one does not exist. I would guess one to have 5 or so wires...

However, you may find it is quicker and easier to just fit a second sensor and use that for your application - any workshop should b able to drill and weld the boss to the pipe that you need.

Another possibility is there a different / later version of your car where the exhaust has two sensors and would that later part fit? Advantage is that it is easily sourced in the future...

Comment: Ty for the answer @Solar Mike, but tapping on the header isn’t an option for me I think because I really didn’t want to pay for labor (I don’t know how to tap) or just replace one of the narrow bands with a wideband (the car has one o2 on each header at the same place) because the ecu uses input from both I believe (but if it doesn’t could I just swap one with a wideband?). Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: No, you can’t swap one as the ecu compares the readings from both sides.

Comment: @sjfklsdafjks you literally drill a hole in the pipe and weld a new bung in place. There's no need to tap anything.